# MYSQL table existence oddity

Tags: mysql

The series of events that lead to this oddity are as follows:

```
mysql> DROP TABLE `mytest`;

ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'mytest'

mysql> CREATE TABLE `mytest` (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,_modified DATETIME, KEY(_modified));

ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`mydb`.`mytest`' already exists

mysql> show tables like '%mytest%';

Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

I initially thought this might be a file permission issue in the data directory, but I have checked and the files that should be present to represent this table do not exist.

This is mysql version 5.1, myisam tables.

I should probably also mention that this occurs during an automated nightly restore of a large database, which is pulled from backup location as a gzipped tar archive, extracted into the mysql data directory and then myisamchk is run against all MYI files in the new directory.

After 2 hours of investigation I am still lost as to what could be causing this - any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: No mytest.* files in the data directory? In the information schema tables (e.g. foreign kerefs which are not enforced in myisam)?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    CREATE TABLE `mytest` IF NOT EXISTS ELSE TRUNCATE `mytest`
```

Use [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) to empty the table and reset cardinality instead of deleting the table and recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
mysql> DROP TABLE '`mydb`.`mytest`'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like broken indexes or definition files.

Try to stop mysql, go to the mysql's data directory, delete the files for the particular table, and restart mysql. Be careful not to delete other files.

If it's InnoDB type, than some command to repair broken tables could help.

IIRC it's `CHECK TABLE ...` and `REPAIR TABLE`.